# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'documentElement' of null, AjAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm making an ajax-jquery function like this :

```
$('.change').live('click',function(){
     $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("h4").offset().top
      }, 2000);

     $('h4').text("Edit Your Video Here :");
     $('.drop').text("Drop Your Updated Video Here...");
     $('.btn').text("Update");

     var videoID = this.id;
     xhr1 = new XMLHttpRequest();

        //initiate request
     xhr1.open('post','beforeUpdate.php',true);//true for asynchronous
     xhr1.setRequestHeader('Content-Type',"multipart/form-data");
     xhr1.setRequestHeader('vidID',videoID);
     xhr1.onreadystatechange = handleResponse;
    xhr1.send(null);     

});

function handleResponse()
{
    if(xhr1.readyState==4)//processing done
     {
        if(xhr1.status == 200)//response okie
        {
            var xmlResponse = xhr1.responseXML;
            root= xmlResponse.documentElement;
            var id = root.getElementsByTagName("ID");
            var name = root.getElementsByTagName("Nama");

            console.log("ID From Server : "+id);
            console.log("Name From Server : "+name);
        }
     }
}
```

So when my button{class=change} is clicked, it will gonna send an ID to beforeUpdate.php, and in this php file I generate an XML file that will be sent back to `xhr1.onreadystatechange = handleResponse;`Here is my beforeUpdate.php file:

```
<?php
require 'databaseConnection.php';
openConnection();   

$headers = apache_request_headers();
$ID = $headers['vidID'];

$hasil = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM video_management where id=$ID");
$result = mysql_fetch_array($hasil);

//$test = "ID = ".$ID."\r\n"."Name = ".$result['Nama'];

//fwrite($myfile, $test);
//fclose($myfile);

//Generating XML FILE
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>';
echo '<response>';
    echo '<ID>';
        echo $ID;
    echo '</ID>';
    echo '<Name>';
        echo $result['Nama'];
    echo '</Name>';
    echo '<Type>';
        echo $result['Type'];
    echo '</Type>';
    echo '<Path>';
        echo $result['videoPath'];
    echo '</Path>';
echo '</response>';
closeConnection();
?>
```

There is nothing wrong when getting data from DB, I can get all data and put them to it's associated xml element.

Then problem is coming from `root= xmlResponse.documentElement;`It's said `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'documentElement' of null,` So What have I done wrong here...???
Thank you so much...! :)

NOTE:
my browser is chrome

Comment: What does `xhr1.responseText` give you?

Comment: Oooowh... yeaat.. I found something from responseText... Gimme a moment Mr. Squint...

Comment: Actually responseText contains my xml response... What's going on here... ?? :v

Comment: generally you would have the readystatechange handler BEFORE you open the connection

Comment: I have done that, but it returns an [object HTMLCollection]  so console.log is looked like this ID From Server : [object HTMLCollection] and Name From Server : [object HTMLCollection]

Comment: I have found the answer... >.<... FInally..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by changing the post method to get method and instead of using these lines :

```
if(xhr1.status == 200)//response okie
        {
            var xmlResponse = xhr1.responseXML;
            root= xmlResponse.documentElement;
            var id = root.getElementsByTagName("ID");
            var name = root.getElementsByTagName("Nama");

            console.log("ID From Server : "+id);
            console.log("Name From Server : "+name);
        }
```

I change it to

```
if(xhr1.status == 200)//response okie
        {
            var xmlResponse = xhr1.responseXML;
            var textResponse = xhr1.responseText;
            console.log("textResponse : "+textResponse);

            //root= xmlResponse.documentElement;
            var id = xmlResponse.getElementsByTagName("ID");
            var name = xmlResponse.getElementsByTagName("Name");

            console.log("ID From Server : "+id[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
            console.log("Name From Server : "+name[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        }
```

Reference :
http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_response.asp

Thanks all.. :)

Comment: That doesn't really make sense. If the original error message was telling you that `xmlResponse` is `null` when trying to get the `.documentElement`, then you should be getting the same error message when accessing `.getElementsByTagName()`, unless you changed something else.

Comment: Ah, that makes a little more sense. :)